# Is 'bitmaprenderer' not a valid value for off-screen canvas rendering context in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, offscreen-canvas

While drawing bitmap image onto off-screen canvas, Chrome console threw an error on me:

> Failed to execute 'getContext' on 'OffscreenCanvas': The provided value 'bitmaprenderer' is not a valid enum value of type OffscreenRenderingContextType.

The problem occurs in both worker and window contexts:

```js
var img = new Image(63, 177);
img.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg";
img.onload = _ => {
 createImageBitmap(img).then(bitmap => {
  var canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(bitmap.width, bitmap.height);
  canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer');
 }).catch(e => console.error(e.message));
};
```

I can get this canvas context type in window context while using (on-screen) canvas interface as so:

```
document.createElement('canvas').getContext('bitmaprenderer');
```

The canvas context is needed in worker, so I can't use (on-screen) canvas interface, there is no document access after all.

While I can just get two-dimensional rendering context of bitmap image by using '2d' identifier in getContext method, it would be OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D and not [ImageBitmapRenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext). I don't know the difference in latency for both interfaces, but as far as I understand, bitmap can be transferred onto canvas immediately, while 2d context should be drawn.

My Chrome version is 74.0.3729.169, and [linked article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext) browser compatibility table stipulates, that bitmap rendering context interface is available from 66 version.

Am I doing something wrong, or is bitmaprenderer not supported as a valid value for off-screen canvas rendering context as of now? How can I access bitmap rendering context for off-screen canvas in Chrome? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, at the time this question was asked [ImageBitmapRenderingContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext) was still not available from an `OffscreenCanvas`, it now is but [Chrome has a bug](https://crbug.com/1410696) which prevents it from rendering to a placeholder canvas.

Note that if you wanted to use this bitmap-renderer for something like being able to draw it to another context, then you could directly pass the `ImageBitmap` to either [2D drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) or [webgl `texImage2d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D).

Also note that in your case, since you are in the main thread and not in a `Worker`, you absolutely don't need an `OffscreenCanvas` and can just do

```js
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Fiore_con_petali_arancioni_SVG.svg";
img.onload = _ => {
  createImageBitmap(img)
    .then(bitmap => {
      const canvas = Object.assign(document.createElement('canvas'), {
        width: bitmap.width,
        height: bitmap.height
      });
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer');
      ctx.transferFromImageBitmap(bitmap);
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
          if (!blob) rej('error');
          res(blob);
        });
      });
    })
    .then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
      result.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
};
```

```html
PNG: <img id="result">
```